# why iptables doesn't seem to close the port 22?

Tags: iptables

```
#iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 42 packets, 3360 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
207  15586 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0    ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       78.12.0.0/14         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
0     0    ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       84.220.0.0/14        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
119  7108  DROP       tcp  --  *      *       !78.12.47.44         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
0     0    DROP       all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 143 packets, 16147 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Standing to these firewall rules, Why in the `auth.log` I find

```
Jan 24 23:51:24 vps45276 sshd[1579]: Invalid user toto from 178.32.42.238
Jan 24 23:51:24 vps45276 sshd[1579]: Received disconnect from 178.32.42.238: 11:
Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 25 00:10:09 vps45276 sshd[1608]: Invalid user serveur from 178.32.42.238
Jan 25 00:10:09 vps45276 sshd[1608]: Received disconnect from 178.32.42.238: 11:
Bye Bye [preauth]
```

What I made wrong with the rules?

Comment: He is asking why, given these rules, there are still ssh connections getting through the firewall.  That is the relationship between `iptables` and `auth.log` in this question.

Comment: @Zoredache Scroll sideways to see the rest of the rule.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Apparently iOS doesn't show horizontal scroll bars... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only `DROP`ped traffic coming in on `eth0`. But the unwanted traffic is almost certainly coming in via a different interface. Remove that qualifier from the final `DROP` rule, and better yet set the `INPUT` table's policy to `DROP`.

Comment: agreed, I'd run a `iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG` to confirm